# В каких методах необходим synchronized

Tags: java, синхронизация, concurrency

Подскажите, есть ли ошибки в рассуждениях. необходимо установить модификатор `synchronized` только тем методам, которым необходимо.Объект класса Solution будет использоваться нитями.

Код задания:

```
public class Solution {
    private double param = Math.random();
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    private void method0() {
        Double d = method3();
    }

    protected void method1(String param1) {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        solution.method0();
    }

    public void method2(int param1) {
        param1++;
    }

    synchronized double method3() {
        double random = Math.random();
        param += 40.7;
        return random + param;
    }

    private synchronized void method4() {
        sb.append(1).append(1).append(1).append(1);
    }

    protected void method5(String param2) {
        new StringBuffer().append(param2).append(param2).append(param2);
    }

    public synchronized String method6(int param2) {
        System.out.println("Thinking....");
        method7(5e-2);
        sb = new StringBuilder("Got it!.");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    String method7(double param2) {
        return "" + param2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

**Рассуждения**

1. приватность или публичность методов не играет роли. Так как доступ к
   ним пойдет из этого же класса
2. method 0 не нужно синхронизировать так как он обращается к
   результату метода 3 который и так синхронизирован
3. method 1 не нужно синзронизировать потому что он ничего не делать ни
   к каким полям не обращается(обращаеться только к методу 0 который
   обращается к методу 3 который уже синхронизирован)
4. method 2 не нужно, так как ни к каким полям класса он не обращается,
   только инкрементит передаваемый параметр, который ни куда не идет.
5. method 3 надо синхронизировать так как идет обращение к полю класса
6. method 4 надо так как stringbuilder не синхронизированный объект, и
       он поле класса.
7. method 5 не надо так как Stringbuffer синхронизирован. Но полем
   класса не является нигде не используется.. (Кстати вопрос: если бы
   было поле класса типа Stringbuffer и метод в него также добавляет,
   видимо все равно не нужно делать synchronized?)
8. method 6 надо так как обращение к полю sb
9. method 7 не надо так как во первых нет обращения к полям.

Comment: Шестой не надо, потому что StringBuilder не выходит за пределы метода (не публикуется)

Comment: А как же тогда return sb.toString(); ? Если поток например использует результат этого метода где-нибудь в другом месте программы? Или так как все остальные методы использующие поле sb  - syncronized другие, они ему мешать не будут?

Comment: А каким образом вызов toString() противоречит написанному? SB по-прежнему никуда не публикуется.

Comment: Например метод начал исполняться одним потоком : sb = new StringBuilder("Got it!."). Далее гонка, поток прерывается и второй поток исполняет method4: b.append(1).append(1).append(1).append(1); Далее снова первый поток продолжает исполнение.  От этого метод toString вернет разные значения: Мы ожидаем Got it!.  А вернется Got it!.1111

Comment: Каким образом? Вы думаете, что когда два потока исполняют один метод, они разделяют между собой переменные метода?

Comment: В данном примере два потока исполняют два разных метода. Но все равно Мьютекс стоит на уровне всего объекта? Первый - начинает method6 - прерывается, второй начинает method4 прерывается, первый выдает поле sb метод toString. Но поле sb не volatile, следовательно возможно оно будет храниться в кеше каждого потока, а может и не будет. Если не будет - тогда ошибка поведения. Мы не получим что ожидали изначально. Но я не уверен. Где я ошибся?

Comment: Это я ошибся, не заметил что SB это поле, а не переменная